# Xamarin Forms Application Crashes without log

Tags: forms, xamarin, crash, report

I'm developing some application using Xamarin Forms that has a function of route following. When it is used in real conditions on a vehicle it crashes whithout any logs in spite of the fact that I'm using AppCenter, i.e. in App.xaml.cs OnStart I added

```
    protected async override void OnStart()
    {
        AppCenter.Start("android=__mycode___" +
                          "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                          "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
                          typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));


        bool hadMemoryWarning = await Crashes.HasReceivedMemoryWarningInLastSessionAsync();
        ErrorReport crashReport = await Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync();

        if (crashReport != null)
        {
            Analytics.TrackEvent(crashReport.StackTrace);
        }
        
    }
```

In fact I tested my app in AppCenter by using Crashes.GenerateTestCrash() and got a test crash report. Besides I caught some errors using this approach. But now there is at least one reason that makes my app crash without any messages to AppCenter. Are there any clues how to resolve this problem?

Comment: As soon as you call `AppCenter.Start` with the `Crashes` type, crashes should automatically be reported in AppCenter. You shouldn't need more. Crashes that don't make it into AppCenter can be tricky, often very hard crashes that will require access to the logs of the device it crashes on.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give advice how to get access to the logs of the device? Especcially how to extract those that relate to my app.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an actual asynchronous event handler.

```
private event EventHandler onStart = delegate { };

protected override void OnStart() {
    onStart += handleStart; //subscribe
    onStart(this, EventArgs.Empty); //raise event
}

private async void handleStart(object sender,EventArgs args) {
    onStart -= handleStart; //unsubscribe
    try {
        AppCenter.Start("android=__mycode___" +
                          "uwp={Your UWP App secret here};" +
                          "ios={Your iOS App secret here}",
                          typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));


        bool hadMemoryWarning = await Crashes.HasReceivedMemoryWarningInLastSessionAsync();
        ErrorReport crashReport = await Crashes.GetLastSessionCrashReportAsync();

        if (crashReport != null) {
            Analytics.TrackEvent(crashReport.StackTrace);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //...handle exception or log as needed
    }        
}
```

`OnStart` is a simple void method and not an actual event handler. This mean that when made async it will become a fire and forget function which wont allow you to catch any exceptions that may have occurred within it.

If it is not caught at startup then it probably means that you are doing something similar somewhere within the app using a non event `async void` that goes uncaught and is crashing the application.

Start by doing a search for any `async void` in your code and checking to make sure that it is an actual event handler.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing actually changed after applying your code. But maybe you give me a clue how to find info about crashes of my app inside device logs?